# Excel 2007 nested function "if, then"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I keep getting a message that I have too many arguments.  I am trying to ask:  If value 1 = x, then value 2; otherwise value 3.  BUT if value 3 = 0, then blank.

It doesn't like:

```
=IF($AX7="SFDC",Z7,AA7,"")
```

It doesn't like:

```
=IF($AX7="SFDC",Z7,AA7,IF(AA7="0",""))
```

I don't know how to ask this question.  Can you help?  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The `IF` function takes three arguments, not four. Your second try had the right idea, but you need to move the second `IF` to the 3rd argument.

```
=IF($AX7="SFDC",Z7,IF(AA7="0","",AA7))
```